# Disable refresh on button in modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problems with my button in my modal. On this button I have put a `onclick`, but the problems is when a click on this one `mouse` or `enter`, the page refresh.

That's I want it's to may click on `ENTER` and my page do my function `connexion()` does not refresh, because a make a AJAX code inside.

This is my modal code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModalLogin" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
     <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
              <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Se connecter</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
              <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-12">
                      <div id='wellconnexion' class="well">


                          <h1 id="TitleHistoriqueconnnexion" class="text-center">Se connecter</h1>
                          <br>

                           <h4 id="ContentHistorique1"></h4>

                          <div id='contentconnexion' class="contentconnexion">
                           <form >
                             <div class="form-group formmarginleft">
                                <input  name="user_login" id="user_login" type="text" placeholder="Identifiant" class="form-control">
                             </div>
                             <div class="form-group formmarginleft">
                                 <input name="user_password" id="user_password" type="password"  placeholder="Mot de passe" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                          <div class="row">
                             <div class="col-12-xs text-center">
                             <button id="validerlogin" onclick="connexion()" value="Se connecter" class="btn btn-primary">Se connecter</button>
                             <div data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-warning">Fermer</div>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                          </form>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Your answers came back fast and furious.  There is hardly a web programmer that has been around a while that has not accidently done this.

Comment: Can you let us see your connexion() function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your onclick function use the preventDefault function to prevent it from reloading the page. That should fix the issue.

https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Answer (score 2):

Set attribute `type` as `button` on your button element:

```
<button type="button" ... >Se connecter</button>
```

By default, button element sets type attribute equal to `submit`, so when you click on this button, your page gets submitted to server.

You can check the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) documentation

> submit: The button submits the form data to the server. This is the default if the attribute is not specified, or if the attribute is dynamically changed to an empty or invalid value.

Comment: Thanks. I have wasted many hours on that just because I do not know default type is "submit"

Answer (score 0):

use preventDefault http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp

on your "connexion()" function....

Comment: why the downvote?...It was the right answer....